# Can I Dynamically Inject a Router View

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I am trying to accomplish something that I am not sure is possible or semantically good. I am building out a personal portfolio website and I liked the idea of a full page navigation where each link transitions into a 90% view and the router view loads in that space(See codepen below for transition example). I've stripped out the main router-view from my codesandbox. I am wondering maybe I need named router views?

Another thing I'd like to know is if I could keep the html semantic at all if I basically inject a `main` tag directing after a nav link? There has to be a better way than how I am doing this. I just need to step back and look at it differently.

CodeSandBox Portfolio:

CodePen Tester for Navigation Transition (I will probably do this a different way using Vue transition components)

See the Pen [Portfolio Nav Tester](https://codepen.io/cjhaviland/pen/LgYZwg/) by CJ Haviland ([@cjhaviland](https://codepen.io/cjhaviland)) on [CodePen](https://codepen.io).